# Obtaining Integer/s (ID #) from a URL based on current webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, google-chrome-extension, integer

im looking on a way to obtain a series of integers from several URLS.

Example.

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/test/systems/121562/data
https://www.mywebsite.com/test/admin/sites/121562
https://www.mywebsite.com/test/admin/site_activations/121562
https://www.mywebsite.com/test/internaladmin/sites/show/121562/reports
```

Now the id (**121562**) is subject to change based on the user.
As well as is not always the same amount of characters, It can be 2 to 6 digits long.

I need to be able to get this ID number by the following code based on the current URL.

My code below here is to the point that it will determine if the url has the part right before the ID.

```
var A = (tab.url.indexOf('systems/') > -1);
var B = (tab.url.indexOf('sites/') > -1);
var C = (tab.url.indexOf('site_activations/') > -1);
var D = (tab.url.indexOf('sites/show/') > -1);

var idcode = Unsure code to pull integers from URL;

if( (A && !B) || (B && !A) ) { 
    chrome.tabs.create({ 
    url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/prod?id=" + idcode,
   }) 

} else {

 alert("Do Something");
}
if( (C && !D) || (D && !C) ) { 
    chrome.tabs.create({ 
    url: "http://www.mywebsite.com/prod?id=" + idcode,
}) 
} else {
alert("Do Something");
}
```

Any ideas, or recommendations would be greatly appreciated it. This code is intended for a Google Chrome widget.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any other numbers in the URL, you can use a simple regular expression to get that:

```
var id = url.match(/([0-9]+)/)[1]
```

Take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/vVL37/

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that the url will always follow one of the following formats (as your code shows):

```
<something>/systems/:id
<something>/sites/:id
<something>/site_activations/:id
<something>/sites/show/:id
```

Then the following regex will pull the 2-6 digit id out for you

```
var idcode = /(?:systems|sites|site_activations|sites\/show)\/(\d{2,6})/.exec(tab.url)[1]
```

If there are other possibilities, then we'll need more info to tune the pattern.